# Get bean name by the object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have two bean configurations:

```
@Bean("name1")
public RabbitTemplate template1(RabbitProperties properties, ConnectionFactory factory) {
    return rabbitCreateOneTemplate(factory, properties.getTemplate());
}

@Bean("name2")
public RabbitTemplate template2(RabbitProperties properties, ConnectionFactory factory) {
    return rabbitCreateTwoTemplate(factory, properties.getTemplate());
}
```

And inject

```
private final RabbitTemplate template;  

public Const( @Qualifier("name1") RabbitTemplate template){  
    this.template = template  
}
```

I want by object `template` to get it name, how to get it?

I know the is `getBeanDefinitionNames()` but it will return the names of all beans, but I need to get the bean name of only a specific object. I want to give `template`  and get "name1", is it possible to do this?

Comment: No. You could get all the beans of a certain type, you then get a map and use that to retrieve the key. You must then hope the objects you are trying to get have a proper equals/hashCode in the objects. Why do you need the name of the injected object? What is it you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm going to save the template bean name and message in the database, then after a while get the template bean from the context by name and send a message

Comment: @KirillZhurbin you need to extend RabbitTemplate class and implement org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware interface

Comment: Feels a bit dangerous. As you now rely on something by name, what if you change the name in between releases?